# strange behavior in jQuery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

Hi i am using jquery version 1.6.2 and jquery validation plugin 1.5.2 ,

i have a custom validator

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("venue_type", function(value, element) {
    if(value>0){return true;}else{return false;}
}, "venue type is required");
```

to check a dropdown value is selected .

i have a form called `venue_edit_form`

```
<form id="venue_edit_form" class="venue_edit_form"
    directory_id="<?php echo $venue_details->DirectoryID; ?>">

//code 


</form>
```

i have added a jquery validation to this form

```
jQuery('#venue_edit_form').validate({
    rules:{
        venueName:{
            required:true,
            minlength:1,
            maxlength:50
        },
        venueDescription :{
            required:false,
            lettersonly:true,
            maxlength:150
        }
    },
    messages:{
        venueName: {
            required:"Venue name is required",
            minlength:"Minimum 1  character required",
            maxlength:"Venue name should not exceed 50 characters"
        }, 
        venueDescription:{                  
            maxlength:"Description should not exceed 150 characters"
        }
    }
});
```

i only validate venue name and description , but when i validate the form this strange thing append.

[image]

an error is coming but i did not validate the drop down in edit form ,
then i check the source

[image]

**there is a custom attribute in the save button called venue_type**

i was surprised and i changed the custom validater name

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("venue_type_validater", function(value, element) {
    if(value>0){return true;}else{return false;}
}, "venue type is required");
```

now it is working fine ,

why was that custom attribute gave error,
i thought jquery validation plugin validates by field name.

is this a bug ????

please tell me what is happening .

thanks in advance .

Comment: do you have metadata plugin in your project

Comment: @ArunPJohny No , i did not use that plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the following code from the validation plugin, it makes use of attributeRules also

```
    var data = $.validator.normalizeRules(
    $.extend(
        {},
        $.validator.classRules(element),
        $.validator.attributeRules(element),
        $.validator.dataRules(element),
        $.validator.staticRules(element)
    ), element);
```

In the attributeRules if an attribute in the element matches a rules name then the rule will get applied to the element

Try

```
jQuery('#venue_edit_form').validate({
    ignore: ':hidden, #venue_edit_save',
    rules:{
        venueName:{
            required:true,
            minlength:1,
            maxlength:50
        },
        venueDescription :{
            required:false,
            lettersonly:true,
            maxlength:150
        }
    },
    messages:{
        venueName: {
            required:"Venue name is required",
            minlength:"Minimum 1  character required",
            maxlength:"Venue name should not exceed 50 characters"
        }, 
        venueDescription:{                  
            maxlength:"Description should not exceed 150 characters"
        }
    }
});
```